# Cartel pack character binding

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Do the cartel market pack items bind to the character that purchases (claims) them?

I know some of the unlocks and armor parts will be bound to the character with which you claim the item. Some allow you to buy an item for all your characters in one item, like the Unlocks.

But if you buy a Tracker's Bounty Pack, or a Hypercrate: Tracker's Bounty Pack, for example, can you transfer the contents at any point after claiming them to any of your alts? Do I have to make sure the character I want to have the item claims them, or can I claim them then mail the packs around to my alts?

And what about after I open the pack? Do the pack contents bind to the character or legacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything from the Cartel Market has a 36-hour period (longer for F2P) after you claim it  during which it is bound to the character that purchased it.  After that, it becomes Bind on Equip/Use or otherwise tradeable/sellable.  Using the item at any point makes it bound permanently.

The same thing happens when you open a Cartel Pack or Cartel gear container, no matter how you obtain it.  The items within are bound for 36 hours and then can be traded.  The exception is things like crafting materials and XP boosts, which can be traded immediately.

Everything you claim from Collections (after previously unlocking it) is Bind on Pickup.

So to directly answer your question: If you want a specific character to open the pack immediately, you should buy/claim it on that character.  If you don't mind waiting 36 hours, you can buy it on another character and trade it later.  I prefer to unlock things on my main, but I always seem to be out of inventory space, so I normally open packs on another character and then mail the items I want over after the waiting period.